# NodeJS on Python : require not defined

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

i'm trying to run javascript on my python script and i got this error : **js2py.internals.simplex.JsException: ReferenceError: require is not defined**

here is my small python script :

```
import js2py

context = js2py.EvalJs(enable_require=True)

code1 = '''
var fs = require('fs');
var File = fs.readFileSync('C:\\Users\\SAMSUNG\\Dropbox\\SB.crx', 'base64');
console.log(File);
'''
f = js2py.eval_js(code1)
print(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you enable `require` in your `context` object, and then you do not use it anywhere. What you want is to execute directly in the context:

```
context.execute(code1)
```

Comment: i tried it and now i'm getting this error : AssertionError: Could not install the required module: fs

Comment: @mouadseghini Sounds like a different question. I suggest you check if you can require the module out of Python first (I'm guessing NodeJS?), try installing it yourself (`npm install <package-name>` and if you can't post a new question with your new problem, and how you attempted to solve it).